# Change screen brightness on a desktop?

Tags: brightness

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on a desktop, so I don't have <kbd>fn</kbd>, and the option doesn't appear in under `System Settings > Screen` as it apparently only appears if your computer is detected to be a laptop.

Is there any way to change screen brightness?

Comment: This was wrongly marked as duplicate... The question that this is supposedly a duplicate of, was asked 1 year after this question...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust your brightness using control settings on your monitor, when using a desktop. There are a couple of ways to control brighness from the CLI, but I just use my hardware controls.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for my desktop. Maybe it will work for you if you are running both operating systems.
I am running Ubuntu alongside windows7. I started up in windows and used the brightness buttons on the side of the screen/computer to set the brightness to the level that was acceptable. You might be able to do it in the windows settings as well. Then I restarted in Ubuntu 11.04 and the screen brightness held. I guess Ubuntu doesn't have the drivers yet for the hardware buttons since my computer is so new. I hope they will add the brightness bar for desktops in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Brightness Controller [image: Install brightness-controller]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller) from the Ubuntu Software Center. If it is not available then download the [.deb file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84627545/brightness_1.0.1_all.deb).

[image: Screenshot 1]

Now you can adjust the brightness using the slider.